# How netbeans find error at time of coding

Tags: java, netbeans

I wonder how netbeans and  other IDE are able to detect error at time of writing code

does it use its own debugging tool or language debugging tool or anything else.

And how i can accomplish it with java programming in basic way

thanks in advance

Comment: Netbeans (as most Java IDE) makes an inkremental Compile of changed Soources. The compiler (which ever is used) will bring an error event, for syntaxerrors.

Comment: by accomplish i just mean.I have made small IDE in java which compile and run with help of processbuilder now i want to add this feature,so how i can add it.I need some reference only.and i am doing it is just for knowledge and any other suggestion is also welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans, eclipse and other IDEs automatically compile your Java code when the source (.java) file is changed.  So when you modify the code and click Save, it compiles it for you and reports warnings/errors (if any).

Comment: thanx for this,but still i have some doubt,On compiling any source file how netbeans get line number on which error has been occured.Is it use some other flags with javac or it parse the error thrown by java compiler or any other compiler